# How to remove required field validation of a parent class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a two classes which is having Required field for List Name. One is a Parent class. How can I avoid or escape the validation for Parent class. I have tried with

ModelState.Remove("ContactModel_ListName");

Below is my model class:

```
public class ContactModel : BaseModel
  {
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public int ListId { get; set; }


   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "List Name")]
   public string List Name { get; set; }
  }


public class ContactUserModel
 {
    public Contact Model Contact Model { get; set; }

 }
```

Comment: I am confused. You write `I have tried with` but then nothing comes. Next you describe your class model. Maybe we are missing some code that you meant to show?

Comment: Maybe if you will add name of programming language to tags, you'll find your answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this, the replaced _ with . now it working fine.

```
ModelState.Remove("ContactModel_ListName");
```

Comment: It looks to me like you forgot to make the fix in your code there. I could be wrong, but from your text it looks like you meant `ContactModel.ListName`?